# vba try finding a directory using many variants of a string?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using vba to try and locate a file that changes name ever so slightly each couple of days. This file is stored on a local intranet system.

The filename is always:

```
Food Specials Rolling Depot Memo xx - xx.xlsm
```

Where xx could represent a different week number e.g.

```
03 - 21
22 - 52
etc..
```

So one day the file may look like:

```
Food Specials Rolling Depot Memo 03 - 21.xlsm
```

The next day it may look like:

```
Food Specials Rolling Depot Memo 22 - 52.xlsm
```

Is there any way i could create 2 strings which contain all my week numbers, (i.e. 01 - 52) and test each of these at random within the file path like so:

```
     WeekNumber1 = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 etc.
    WeekNumber2 = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 etc.



    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sURL & "Food%20Specials%20Rolling%20Depot%20Memo%20" & WeekNumber1 & "%20-%20" & WeekNumber2 & ".xlsm")

MsgBox wb

On Error GoTo 0
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this on a SharePoint site? I notice that you have `sUrl` in the `.Open` call and the filename is url encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way using `Like`:

```
Sub GetTheName()
    Dim s As String, FileName As String

    s = "C:\TestFolder\*.xlsm"

    FileName = Dir(s)

    Do Until FileName = ""
        If FileName Like "Food Specials Rolling Depot Memo*" Then MsgBox FileName
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I get a Loop without do error? Any ideas?

Comment: Actually sorted. Was missing an end If before loop. Although now the code doesn't seem to be finding the file :/ not getting any message

Comment: @Bing.Wong  Make sure the filename spelling is correct **including all the spaces**.

Answer (score 1):

a proposition, as I am not sure that the dir() function does work on sharepoint/internet site

```
Sub test()
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To 52
        For j = i To 52

            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sURL & "Food%20Specials%20Rolling%20Depot%20Memo%20" & format(i,"00") & "%20-%20" & format(j,"00" & ".xlsm")
            If Not wb Is Empty Then Exit For
        Next j
        If Not wb Is Empty Then Exit For
    Next i
    If wb Is Empty Then
        MsgBox "could not find file"
    Else
        MsgBox "found " & wb.Name
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this, however, it always returns file not found :(

Comment: I think the problem might be that i and j are both returning 1. Numbers will need to be double digits, i.e. 01

Comment: Edit of last comment: I think the problem might be that i and j are both returning 1. Numbers will need to be double digits, i.e. 01 since the file name will be written Food Specials Rolling Depot Memo 01 - 19.xlsm etc

Comment: I have edited the code to include double digit formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Dir`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx) function to iterate over all files matching your wildcard:

```
Dim wildcard as String
Dim fileName as String

' Prepend a path to look in a directory different from the current directory
wildcard = "Food Specials Rolling Depot Memo ?? - ??.xlsm"
fileName = Dir(wildcard)
Do While fileName <> ""
    ' Process fileName
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName)

    fileName = Dir()
Loop
```

Comment: @Bing.Wong I'm pretty sure my code works as described so perhaps you can elaborate on why it doesn't work for you? If `Dir(wildcard)` returns the empty string then there are no files having that wildcard. The problem may be as simple as not specifying the correct path in the wildcard.

Comment: it just seems to keep returning "Food Specials Rolling Depot Memo ?? - ??.xlsm" over and over again.

Comment: @Bing.Wong: That doesn't make any sense. If you read the linked documentation the function clearly performs as I explain. Also, when I try to run the exact code that I have provided (without having any files matching the wildcard) the empty string is returned as expected. There must be some discrepancy between my code and environment (Excel 2016) and yours.